# Airflow - DAG Integrity Testing - sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: variable

Tags: airflow

I am trying to write some DAG integrity tests in airflow. The issue I am coming across is the DAG that I am testing, I have references to variables in some of the tasks within that DAG.

eg: Variable.get("AIRFLOW_VAR_BLOB_CONTAINER")

I seem to be getting the error:
**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: variable**

from this because when testing via pytest, those variables (and the variables table) don't exist. Does anyone know any workarounds or suggested methods to handle Variables/Connection references when running DAG Integrity tests?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a local metastore for testing. Running `airflow db init` without any other settings will create a SQLite metastore in your home directory which you can use during testing. My default additional settings for a local metastore for testing are:

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS=False  (to ensure there are no defaults to make things magically work)
AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False  (to ensure there are no defaults to make things magically work)
AIRFLOW__CORE__UNIT_TEST_MODE=True  (Set default test settings, skip certain actions, etc.)
AIRFLOW_HOME=[project root dir]  (To avoid Airflow files in your home dir)
```

Running `airflow db init` with these settings results in three files in your project root dir:

1. unittests.db
2. unittests.cfg
3. webserver_config.py

It's probably a good idea to add those to your `.gitignore`. With this set up you can safely test against the local metastore `unittests.db` during your tests (ensure that when running pytest, the same env vars are set).

Alternatively, if you don't want a local metastore for reasons, you will have to resort to mocking to substitute the call Airflow makes to the metastore. This requires knowledge of the internals of Airflow. An example:

```py
import datetime
from unittest import mock

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


def test_bash_operator(tmp_path):
    with DAG(dag_id="test_dag", start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1), schedule_interval="@daily") as dag:
        with mock.patch("airflow.models.variable.Variable.get") as variable_get_mock:
            employees = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]
            variable_get_mock.return_value = employees
            output_file = tmp_path / "output.txt"
            test = BashOperator(task_id="test", bash_command="echo {{ var.json.employees }} > " + str(output_file))
            dag.clear()
            test.run(
                start_date=dag.start_date,
                end_date=dag.start_date,
                ignore_first_depends_on_past=True,
                ignore_ti_state=True,
            )

            variable_get_mock.assert_called_once()
            assert output_file.read_text() == f"[{', '.join(employees)}]\n"
```

These lines:

```py
with mock.patch("airflow.models.variable.Variable.get") as variable_get_mock:
    employees = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]
    variable_get_mock.return_value = employees
```

Determine that the function `airflow.models.variable.Variable.get` isn't actually called but instead this list is returned: `["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]`. Since `task.run()` doesn't return anything, I made the `bash_command` write to a `tmp_path`, and read the file to assert if the content is what I expected.

This avoids the need for a metastore entirely, but mocking can be a lot of work and complex once your tests grow beyond basic examples like these.